# HTML: <map> <area> working only in webkit browsers

Tags: html

Wrote this HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="logo">Mysite</h1>
            <img id="links" src="images/links.png" usemap="map" width="946" height="562" alt="links">

            <map name="map">
                <area id="shape1" shape="poly" coords="0,377,185,192,370,377,185,562" href="http://www.test.com" alt="asdsad">
                <area id="shape2" shape="poly" coords="193,185,378,0,563,185,378,370" href="http://www.test.com" alt="asdsad">
                <area id="shape3" shape="poly" coords="384,377,569,192,754,377,569,562" href="http://www.test.com" alt="asdasd">
                <area id="shape4" shape="poly" coords="576,185,761,0,946,185,761,370" href="http://www.test.com" alt="sdfsdf">
            </map>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

BUT area links work ONLY in webkit browsers, the others just ignore it.
Can anyone help me? Or any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: its not unsupported, it just contains a syntax error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

on the `<img>` tag: `usemap="#map"`